# not enough storage space available to process this command

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer

I am using windows vista and IE7.

I was trying to upgrade to IE8 or update my IE7.
Either way i am getting the error message

```
not enough storage space available to process this command
```

This comes after i try to download ,run and execute the IE updates from the msn website.
Kindly help cant figure out wat the issue is.

Comment: may be this belongs to superuser.com

Comment: Sounds a little like your C-Drive is full...

Comment: How much memory have you got installed/free?

Comment: Not necessarily C:... Windows temporarily stores update files on the last local drive.  (I have no idea why they thought this was a good idea.)  If you have more than one drive make sure the last one has some free space.

Comment: and when I add  "Temporary Internet Files" to the to "\Windows" access Temp folder...i get an message "Running a command on this system might be unsafe.Do you want to continue?"

Comment: I think 176 MB is too less. Also that space will be heavily fragmented. Hence would mostly be not so useful for any real work. Clean up the disk. Move something from C:\ to an other drive. Also you can reclaim a lot of space by deleting "Windows.old" folder. This is basically the backup of your old Windows Partition.

Comment: its actually 176 GB of  free  space in C:/ drive.

Answer (score 2):

1. I assume your Windows is installed on C:\ (Windows Drive). If yes check if there is enough space on the drive. (1-2 GB will suffice.).
2. How much RAM do you have. If its less than 1 GB, then increase it to min 1 GB (recommended atleast 2GB).
3. How much is your Page File size? It must be atleast equal to your RAM size (not sure on that calculation). Also by default, the space for the page file is allocated on Windows Drive i.e C:\. So make sure there is enough space for the page file to auto grow if required.
4. Make sure your temp folder is empty (recommended) or atleast has enough space for IE installer to extract & run. Try using [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/download) which will easily clean up temp for you. type %TEMP% in Run prompt to see your temp folder. Again temp folder is mostly present on Windows drive i.e. C:\.
5. Just for the heck of it, do a "Run As Administrator" while launching the installer. (IE installer will be smart enough to do that, but still)

Comment: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp...there are files to the total of 936MB.Is it OK to clear the folder completely?

Comment: Yup. But use CCleaner. It will try to delete the unnecessary files but will skip all locked files.